# Делаю возможность добавлять лайк но выходит ошибка

Tags: python, django

Выводит ошибку предполагаю что проблема в адресе  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

шаблон лайка

```
{% extends "ShapeHtml/wrapper.html" %}


{% block content %}

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h1 class=" text-info">{{object.title}}</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p> {{object.post|safe|linebreaks}}  </p>
        <h3 align="right" class=" text-info"> Опубликованно: {{articles.date|date:"d-m-Y в H:i"}}</h3>
    </div>

    <p class="post-meta">
        ТЕГИ:
            {% for tag in articles.tags.all %}
            <a href="{% url 'post_list_by_tag' tag.slug %}"> {{ tag.name }}</a> |
            {% endfor %}
    </p>

    <a href="{% url 'addlike' article.pk %}">
        Лайк
    </a>


     <h1> <a href="/discussion/"> Обсуждения </a> </h1>


{% endblock %}
```

views.py

```
def addlike(request, article_id):
    if article_id in request.COOKIES:
        response = HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:


        article = get_object_or_404(Articles, id=article_id)  # возвращает id статьи или 404.
        article.article_likes += 1  # Прибавляет единицу к article_likes
        article.save()  # сохраняет
        response = HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        response.set_cookie(article_id, "test")
        return response
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

class Articles(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 200)
    post = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='', default="default_value")
    tags = TaggableManager()
    article_like = models.IntegerField(default='0')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns=[
    path('', ArticlesList.as_view(), name='articles_list'),
    path('<int:pk>/', ArticleDetail.as_view(), name='article_detail'),
    path('aboutUs', views.aboutUs, name='aboutUs'),
    path('tag/<tag_slug>.+/', views.post_list, name='post_list_by_tag'),
    path('addlikes/<int:pk>/', views.addlike, name='article')
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Возможно в шаблоне лайка у вас ссылка генерируется без `article.id`?

Comment: А как сделать чтобы генерировалось с artilce.id

Comment: Пока непонятно. Добавьте шаблон и представление, отвечающие за отображение article.

Answer (score 0):

Я решил проблемму

views.py
в функции после request записал pk

```
def addlike(request,pk):
    if pk in request.COOKIES:
        response = HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:


        article = get_object_or_404(Articles, id=pk)  # возвращает id статьи или 404.
        article.article_likes += 1  # Прибавляет единицу к article_likes
        article.save()  # сохраняет
        response = HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        response.set_cookie(pk, "test")
        return response
```

изменил urls

```
path('<int:pk>/', views.addlike, name='pk')
```

и наконец шаблон

```
<a href="{{ article.pk }}">
    Лайк
</a>
```