# Все еще делаю возможность оставлять лайки на сайте

Tags: html, python, django

Теперь новая проблема вот скрин проблема во views при добавлении лайков

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

views.py

```
def addlike(request, pk):
    if pk in request.COOKIES:
        response = HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:


        article = get_object_or_404(Articles, id=pk)  # возвращает id статьи или 404.
        article.article_like += 1  # Прибавляет единицу к article_likes
        article.save()  # сохраняет
        response = HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        response.set_cookie(pk, "test")
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')  # делает редирект на ту же страницу
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns=[
    path('', ArticlesList.as_view(), name='articles_list'),
    path('<int:pk>/', ArticleDetail.as_view(), name='article_detail'),
    path('aboutUs', views.aboutUs, name='aboutUs'),
    path('tag/<tag_slug>.+/', views.post_list, name='post_list_by_tag'),
    path('<int:pk>/like', views.addlike, name='pk')

]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

post.html

```
{% extends "ShapeHtml/wrapper.html" %}


{% block content %}

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h1 class=" text-info">{{object.title}}</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p> {{object.post|safe|linebreaks}}  </p>
        <h3 align="right" class=" text-info"> Опубликованно: {{articles.date|date:"d-m-Y в H:i"}}</h3>
    </div>

    <p class="post-meta">
        ТЕГИ:
            {% for tag in articles.tags.all %}
            <a href="{% url 'post_list_by_tag' tag.slug %}"> {{ tag.name }}</a> |
            {% endfor %}
    </p>

    <a href=" like {{ article.pk }}">
        Лайк
    </a>


     <h1> <a href="/discussion/"> Обсуждения </a> </h1>


{% endblock %}
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

class Articles(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 200)
    post = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='', default="default_value")
    tags = TaggableManager()
    article_like = models.IntegerField(default='0')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Нажал на Switch Key вот текст после

Traceback:

```
File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\Desktop\RapterGame.com\RapterGames\news\views.py" in addlike
  59.         response.set_cookie(pk, "test")

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\http\response.py" in set_cookie
  169.         self.cookies[key] = value

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\cookies.py" in __setitem__
  495.             self.__set(key, rval, cval)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\cookies.py" in __set
  485.         M.set(key, real_value, coded_value)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\cookies.py" in set
  349.         if key.lower() in self._reserved:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /news/2/like
Exception Value: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Comment: Нажмите на странице ошибки ссылку "Switch to copy-and-paste view", из появившегося поля скопируйте текст, начинающиеся с Traceback, и вставьте в вопрос.

Comment: Пока можно только сказать, что где-то в коде есть попытка работы с целым числом как со строкой.

Comment: Все сделал добавил в код

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Делаю возможность добавлять лайк но выходит ошибка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/999183/%d0%94%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%8e-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первый аргумент [response.set_cookie()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.set_cookie) должен быть строкой, а у вас это число. Исправить можно так: `response.set_cookie(str(pk), "test")`, но лучше для имени cookie выбрать более внятное название.

Comment: Как сделать строчку ?

Comment: response.set_cookie(str(pk), "test")

Answer (score 3):

Вы пытаетесь ключом cookie сделать целое число, а должна быть строка

```
path('<int:pk>/like', views.addlike, name='pk')
```

вот тут возникает проблема

```
response.set_cookie(pk, "test")
```

может вы хотели сделать так?

```
response.set_cookie("test", pk)
```

притом у вас return затирается `HttpResponseRedirect('/')` вам нужно возвращать изменённый ответ, а не новый

```
return response
```

Comment: а как сделать сроку ?

Comment: почитайте доку по python